# Handling variables multiple times in Reverse-Mode Automatic Differentiation

Tags: automatic-differentiation, differentiation

If I try to derive a function computationally with Reverse-Mode Auto-Diff, I can derive a single function wrt. many variables in a single go.

My Issue is now, what happens, if I input this function (just a very simple example of the problem):

$f(x,y,z)=(x + y)*z+x$

Now, obviously, handling this manually is simple, just derive both subexpressions of the topmost $+$ and add them after that.

But in Reverse-Mode AD, the end result of each derivation is at the bottom of each branch(if you envision the function as a expression tree). Now, how do you handle these cases, as most algorithms handle a $+$ by just splitting of, and recursively handling the subtrees. But then for a derivation wrt. to $x$ for $x=2, y=2, z=2$ I get $f'(x=2)=1$ and $f'(x=2)=2$ depending in which subtree I am.

I think I am missing a crucial part of Reverse-Mode AD(mainly probably in the implementation part) but I don't know which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one can "store" the results of these subexpressions and later on, add all of them up.

Think of having an extra variable assigned for each variable of the function, all of them initialised with 0, and adding all of these sub values up to each of the corresponding storage values, and once all subtrees are finished, the stored values should have the correct values.

For every one reading this, does this seem right to you?